# Piecemaker , 3dslider not working ( its not showing up on the site)

Tags: flash, wordpress, jquery-plugins, flashvars

i need help with the "piecemaker" flash plugin, by [modularweb](http://www.modularweb.net)...

i used this theme by wordpress 
    http://www.web2feel.com/womack/
by default an image should show up by default but my site shows empty space.

this is my site
    http://www.vkalai.com

the swf file is not showing up.
here is the code for the header which Im using. someone plz help me. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in the piecemaker.xml file, try specifying absolute urls to your images and sources. wherever you encounter the word

```
source = "contents/something.ext"
```

make it

```
source = "http://www.vkalai.com/path_to_your_piecemaker_folder/contents/something.ext"
```

this solved the problem for me in one previous case. let us know if it worked.

Comment: @ aditya menon this is the part right? 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

<title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

Comment: no, that is the html markup of the main document - i am talking about the ".xml" you will find somewhere in your wp folder - most likely the extensions folder (i'm not sure about where that is in wordpress). try searching for ".xml" in the entire folder inside your local drive... make changes to it and upload...